# SQl Server Merge Adjacent duplicate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table Data is as follows, I would like to select minimum of the updated date with Name. Need to merge name if adjacent names are same. and Select the records in Ascending order of date updated

```
Name UpdatedDate
L     05-May-2022
S     09-May-2022
S     09-May-2022
A     10-May-2022
A     15-May-2022
L     16-May-2022
S     17-May-2022
S     19-May-2022
K     01-May-2022
```

Expected Output

```
Name UpdatedDate
K     01-May-2022 
L     05-May-2022
S     09-May-2022 
A     10-May-2022 
L     16-May-2022
S     17-May-2022
```

Comment: Are you looking to select or actually delete rows in the table?

Comment: Also, are your dates always going to be in ascending order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that:

1. Your dates are always in ascending order AND
2. Your version of SQL Server supports LEAD and Lag functions

You can try this:

```
SELECT NAME, UPDATEDDATE
FROM
(SELECT NAME, UPDATEDDATE, LAG(NAME, 1, 'DEFAULTVALUE') OVER (ORDER BY UPDATEDDATE) AS LAGNAME) T
WHERE T.NAME <> T.LAGNAME
```

This uses lag to find which rows belong to the same "group" based on the Name column, and then takes the first row, which should also have the earliest date going by assumption 1.

Comment: Dates are not always in ascending order in the table but the expected output should be in ascending order of the dates. Thank you

Comment: This solution also works for your updated data. Are you saying that you can have random order of dates within same "group" e.g. L - May 02, L - May 01, L - May 03?

Comment: yes. In that case L may be repeated ,if some other name falls in between the L dates

Comment: I dont get you. Your example data already shows that you can have sequence like L,S,S,A,A, and then again L. But if you have L 3 times in a row, can the dates be in random order for those 3 rows?

Comment: working good, thank you

Answer (score -1):

Using Group By. `Select Name, UpdatedDate from YourTable Group By Name, UpdatedDate`